# Applescript couldn't start an application

Tags: macos, applescript

I wrote a simple applescript to start to a program called "SelfControl" during startup, while I run the script with applescript editor, it launch the "SelfControl" app, but while I export the script as application, the app won't launch. I change the code to launch other app and is working fine.

I also change permission of SelfControl app to full read write access. Still no luck. Any idea what cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what cause the problem, I named my applescript code as "SelfControl" and in my code I tell "SelfControl" to activate, which perhaps it try to launch itself than the app I want to launch.